# Error with my game?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

```
from random import randint

random_number = randint(1, 10)

guesses_left = 3
# Start of the game
while guesses_left != 0:
   def guess():
        guess = int(input("What is your guess?"))
        if guess > 10:
        print ("Insert value between 1 and 10")
        guesses_left += 1
    guess()
if guess == random_number:
    print ("You win")
    break
guesses_left -= 1
else:
    print ("You lose")
```

I am making this game where random numbers are formed and the user guesses the random number to win the game. However, I want to implement a safety that if the guess goes over 10, then it will print "enter value from 1 to 10" (see the code) and also add 1 to the  guess left. I made this into a function so that the print message keeps displaying itself until the user puts all his guesses from 1 to 10. I am getting an error in that function itself :(

Also, how can I keep displaying the print message without functions? I know how to do it with while loop but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: always add full error message.

Comment: you  have wrong indentation

Comment: Immediate observation, your indentation inside the function is wrong

Comment: You're also playing a dangerous game with a nested function and renaming that function within its body.

Comment: you don't need function - you need correct indentation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the function at all, since you don't call it more than once.

A good way to think about the problem is that the program starts with a state of not knowing what the players guess is. You can represent this as 0. Then the while loop checks to see if the guess is >=1 AND <=20. Since the first time around, it's not, the loop would ask for a guess between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
random_number = 10 # randint(1, 10)
guesses_left = 3

# Start of the game
while guesses_left != 0:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
    if guess > 10:
        print "(error: insert a value between 1 and 10)"
        guesses_left = guesses_left - 1 #add if you want to dock them a guess for not following instructions :)
    else:
        if guess is random_number:
            print ("You win!")
            break
        else:
            print "Nope!"
            guesses_left = guesses_left - 1
    if guesses_left is 0:
        print "Wah Wah. You lose."
```

My code is probably more verbose than it needs to be but it does the trick. There are a couple problems with the way you wrote the script.

- Like Hack Saw said, I don't think you need the function.
- Indentation is off. This matters a lot to python

Good luck in class! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :D but what if I want to call the input again and again? I still should not use functions? And when should I use functions? I am very confused about fucntions. 
One more thing, I see you use "is" like "guess is random_number". In python, "is" == "="? 
Thank you for your revised code. It helps a lot in finding my mistakes and areas I can improve upon. I am currently learning from codecademy so if you can guide me to some helpful websites for learning python, I will be very grateful. Thank you :)

Comment: Sure. No problem. Can you explain the context - how or why you want to call the function again?. Here's the answer to 'is' vs '='. Keep working! Good luck and check out Euler when you're looking for interesting challenges - https://projecteuler.net

Comment: What program do you type on? Notepad++? Is there something better than that? Thank you :) I wanted to call the function so that I can repeat the input statement again and again.

Comment: There are thinks far better than Notepad. Take a look at PyCharm, for one. I use the Community edition.

Comment: Making it a function doesn't actually help you call it repeatedly. The while loop does that just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Several notes here:

1) Remove the definition of the guess function outside of the while loop.

2) Watch the indentation. It's meaningful in Python

3) I merged the guess function with the main code, and it's still pretty readable

4) You can avoid having to increment guesses_left by 1 if you don't decrement it

5) I really hope you're trying to learn programming, and not having us complete your homework for you. Python can be very powerful, please continue to learn about it.

```
from random import randint
random_number = randint(1, 10)

guesses_left = 3

# Start of the game
win=False
while guesses_left>0:
    guess=int(input("What is your guess?"))
    if guess==random_number:
        win=True
        break
    elif guess>10:
        print("Insert value between 1 and 10")
        continue
    else:
        guesses_left -= 1
if win:
    print("You win")
else:
    print("You lose")
```

Comment: Yes sir. I am very serious about learning python. I installed kivy for python to get into android development later down the road. Currently I am learning from codecademy. Any other helpful learning websites that will aid me will be very helpful. Thank you sir

Comment: Sir, I did not understand your continue statement in the elif? what does that do? Sorry for beginner question.

Comment: `continue` is used inside an iterative block to start the next iteration without running anything which comes after `continue`.
I guess you can do without that continue statement as if/elif is the last block under while.

Comment: You don't check if the input value is less than one.